# How I can install multiple versions of php in ubuntu 22.10 version?

Tags: apache2, php, 22.10

I'm a PHP web developer I have some errors with new version of ubuntu, I was Installed new version of Ubuntu (22.10) but  when I installed php 8.2 version I can't know how to install different version of PHP.

For example I tried to install php 8.0, 7.4, 7.0, 7.2 , ... but nothing happened I was tried many ways, please if someone know how to install multiple versions in ubuntu 22.10 ask me.

Thank You.

Comment: If you are familiar with Docker containers, they are ideal for this sort of situation. I can have several containers running simultaneously, each with different versions of PHP, each reading the same source files. This allows for some excellent unit testing 

Answer (score 5):

You can try this step :

1. Add PPA for PHP

   `sudo apt install software-properties-common`
   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
   `sudo apt-get update`
2. Install PHP8.0

   `sudo apt install php8.0`
3. Install PHP 8 Packages That You Need
   Example :

   `sudo apt install php8.0-common php8.0-mysql php8.0-xml`
4. Enable PHP 8 and Restart Your Apache

   `sudo a2dismod php8.2`
   `sudo a2enmod php8.0`
5. Check php version that now running

   `php -v`

If it’s still show old php version then you can run bellow command and choose new php version from there list. so run bellow command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Repeat that step for another version that you want to running with your apache.

Hope this help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look here (is for Ubuntu 22.04 but I think it would be OK for 22.10 too):

https://techvblogs.com/blog/install-multiple-php-versions-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Links change and break. Answers should be self-contained and not require leaving the site. Please delete this answer and post a comment to the question. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to managing packages and handling multiple versions in different operating systems, the experience can vary greatly. While Windows offers a smooth experience, Mac and Linux can be challenging, especially if you are not familiar with Linux commands.

One solution to this is using the "**brew**" package manager, which provides a range of useful functionalities for managing packages and multiple versions. This is a great alternative to other package managers such as "apt" or custom repositories.

[Click to learn more about Homebrew](https://linux.how2shout.com/install-brew-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-linux/)